# how to print javafx pane?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a pane in my javafxml file named **receiptPane**. I like to print this pane as it contains tableview, and labels.
I know how to print the node but somehow I couldn't figure it out to print the pane.
If I a put any node here it works, it prints the node. But, if I put my pane here, it doesn't print out.

```
@FXML
public void print() {
   // Create a printer job for the default printer
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(receiptPane.getScene().getWindow())){
        boolean success = job.printPage(receiptPane);
        if (success) {
            job.endJob();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure out the problem since I asked my question.
Here is the reason why do I get blank print.
Normally it was printing but it was printing blank. So I tried to create an instance of that pane and add all those nodes inside.
It is normally added but, I did that in Scene Builder. I think that was my problem.

So, solution is here below;

```
 receiptPane = new Pane();
    receiptPane.getChildren().addAll(totalL,
            tAmountL,
            dateTimeL,
            orderIDL,
            compNameL,
            compAddress1L,
            compAddress2L,
            thanksL,
            paymentType1L,
            paymentTypeAmount1L,
            dueL,
            dueAmountL,
            ordReceipts
    );
 PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(receiptPane.getScene().getWindow())){
    boolean success = job.printPage(receiptPane);
    if (success) {
        job.endJob();
    }
}
```

Now, It works.

Thanks for anyone interested.